# How to add sprites to a raycaster engine

Tags: javascript

I have managed to get textured walls working in my ray caster engine. I am now hoping to add sprites into this engine so i can implement enemies. I have attempted to implement this myself but i cant seem to get it to work. any help is appreciated!

Comment: Gotta give a lot more information buddy. Like what framework are you using?  Your textured walls are basically sprites, so enemies are essentially the same thing just positioned differently.  Code example also helps.